# Greedy sequential/parallel task scheduling

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, scheduling, greedy

We have `N` tasks that need to be scheduled for processing. Each task consists of two parts that need to executed in order. The first one is guarded by a mutex and therefore only one task can be executing this part at a time. The second part has no such constraint and any number of the tasks can be executing this at the same time. For task `i` we know how much time it needs to spend in each part, namely m<sub>i</sub> for the guarded part, and a<sub>i</sub> for the part that can be executed in parallel.

The problem is to find a permutation of the tasks such that the time needed to execute all of them is minimized.

My intuition says that this can be solved with a greedy algorithm, by scheduling the tasks in descending a<sub>i</sub> order.

For example given the tasks with: 
m<sub>1</sub> = 3, a<sub>1</sub> = 9 
m<sub>2</sub> = 2, a<sub>2</sub> = 7 
m<sub>3</sub> = 6, a<sub>3</sub> = 10

The optimal solution is the permutation 3, 1, 2 where the tasks overlap as follows (pluses being the time spent in part 1 and minuses being the time spent in part 2):

```
3 ++++++---------- (6, 10)
1       +++--------- (3,9)
2          ++------- (2,7)
Total time needed: 6+3+2+7: 18
```

Any other permutation gives a higher total time needed, e.g.:

```
1 +++--------- (3,9)
2    ++------- (2,7)
3      ++++++---------- (6, 10)
Total time needed: 3+2+6+10: 21
```

However, I have trouble proving that the greedy solution is optimal. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Could you clarify how the optimal permutation is 3, 1, 2?

Comment: I edited the main question to clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've posted a proof below. I tried to give as detailed an answer as I could. Please ask if you have any questions or if I made a logical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a pretty clever answer for this question with a proof by contradiction over as [cs.stackexchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/127479/greedy-sequential-parallel-task-scheduling/127486#127486).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this question, let us first write an equation to calculate the total time it takes for N tasks.

This equation is:
t = m<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> + max((a<sub>2</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> - a<sub>1</sub>), (a<sub>3</sub> + m<sub>3</sub> - a<sub>2</sub>), ...).

The first part of this equation (m<sub>1</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> + ...) is the time it takes for the first task

The second part of the equation is more complicated. Simply, the max() calculates the maximum amount of task time that does not overlap with the first task (in your example, this maximum time is 9).

Let us now prove the optimal solution through induction. Suppose the optimal answer for n tasks is ordering in descending a<sub>i</sub> order. Then, if we introduce another a<sub>n+1</sub> and m<sub>n+1</sub> and a<sub>n+1</sub> is the smallest value of a<sub>i</sub> (we can assume this through inductive hypothesis), a<sub>n+1</sub> should go to the bottom of the list.

To prove this, suppose a<sub>n+1</sub> went to any other position, say i. Then the values of a<sub>i+1</sub> + m<sub>i+1</sub> - a<sub>n</sub> would obviously be greater than it was previously (and even greater than a<sub>n</sub> + m<sub>n</sub> - a<sub>i-1</sub>). Therefore, the max() function will return a value greater than or equal to its previous value.

Now we have to prove the inductive hypothesis for n = 2. Suppose that we had a<sub>1</sub> and a<sub>2</sub>.

The value of the equation t = m<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> - a<sub>1</sub>, which simplifies to t = m<sub>1</sub> + a<sub>2</sub> + m<sub>2</sub> is now of interest.

It is trivial to see that a<sub>2</sub> must be the lesser value for this equation to be minimized. Therefore, the inductive hypothesis has been proven.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I think that the equation for t is incorrect. In the case of just 2 tasks it would give us: t = m1+a2+m2. Assuming an example with a1=2, m1=5, a2=1, m2=1 it would give us t=3, while the correct t is 7.

Comment: Am I missing something? m1 + m2 + a2 = 5+1+1 = 7